# Using multi-processing for MCMC code

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pymc, mcmc

I am a newbie **pymc** user and I have written an MCMC code which is quite slow and I would like to modify my code in order to speed it up. Is it possible to use multi-processing to speed up the performance of pymc? For instance if I have a `make_model` function which consists of bunch of deterministic and stochastic and potential classes, and I am interested to find the posterior for couple of parameters. If the structure of my MCMC code would be as following:

```
def make_model(X):
    .
    .
    return locals()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    M = pm.MCMC(make_model(X)),db='pickle',dbname='NFWTracer.pickle')
    M.use_step_method(pm.AdaptiveMetropolis, M.model_pars ,verbose=1)
    M.isample(40000,8000,50)
```

How could I use multi-processing while all the chains are related in order to decide the next steps  in the parameter space? If it is plausible, how it should be done?

Comment: do you have example code that can be run?

Comment: @shavenwarthog well I have an MCMC code which is slow but I am wondering whether it makes sense to use multi-processing and where I should use it, for instance inside the `make_model` function? Especially the bottleneck is likelihood and I wrote whole the process of likelihood in cython, therefore the only other option to improve the speed of the code is multi-processing or paralleling the code.